# Translate Mongo Json Command to Spring Query Object

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework

Could somebody pls tell me what the correct Spring Aggregation Object for this mongodb shell command would be:

```
{$sort: {labelId:1, dataId:1, updatedAt:1}}, 

{$group:
  {
    "_id": 
        {
            "lid" : "$labelId", 
            "dataId":"$dataId"
        }, 
    "dat":
        {
            $last:"$updatedAt"
        }, 
    "value":
        {
            $last:"$value"
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it with spring-mongo like this:

```
    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            sort(Direction.ASC,"labelId")
              .and(Direction.ASC,"dataId")
              .and(Direction.ASC,"updatedAt"),
            group(Fields.fields().and("labelId","lid").and("dataId"))
              .last("updatedAt").as("dat")
              .last("value").as("value")
    );
```

As a little tip, I like to have something around to dump the pipeline before I run things:

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    // debug pipeline
    System.out.println(
        gson.toJson(
            gson.fromJson(aggregation.toDbObject("spring", Aggregation.DEFAULT_CONTEXT).toString(), Object.class)
        )
    );
```

Which gives me a pretty serialized output to check:

```
{
  "aggregate": "spring",
  "pipeline": [
    {
      "$sort": {
        "labelId": 1.0,
        "dataId": 1.0,
        "updatedAt": 1.0
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": {
          "labelId": "$lid",
          "dataId": "$dataId"
        },
        "dat": {
          "$last": "$updatedAt"
        },
        "value": {
          "$last": "$value"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I execute this Aggregation when I the result is a different class than the Collection I am querying?

Comment: @skylla This is common for aggregation output. It's generally best to use `DBObject.class` as in `mongoOperation.aggregate(aggregation, "spring", DBObject.class)`. Alternately, define a class to the expected output shape and do a typed aggregation using that class for output.